# What are some loop optimizations that can be applied to vector summation?

Tags: compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I’m trying to figure out what are some loop optimizations (in compilers) that can be applied to (linear algebra) vector summation?

Vector sum is defined

```py
for i in range(len(vector1)):
     vector_result[i] = vector1[i] + vector2[i]
```

How can I optimize this?

Some loop optimizations I’m aware of:

1. Loop fission
2. Loop fusion
3. Vectorization
4. Tiling
   But I don’t know how any of these can be applied to the summation of vectors.

If anybody out there know a thing or two about compilers and loop optimizations i will appreciate if you give me an example of the code after a loop optimization is applied. Thanks

Comment: Tiling isn't applicable since this is just one pass over two arrays.  To make it more cache-friendly, you'd have to consider the bigger picture of the code that writes these arrays (can you sum on the fly while doing that, or write a piece then sum it?)

Comment: If you actually meant `Sum += v1[i] + v2[i]`, then yes, you'd want to vectorize and unroll with multiple accumulators to hide FP latency, as in a dot product which has the same dependency pattern.  (But it can use FMA, this can't since it's all additions.)  See links at the top of my answer on [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45114487), and that answer itself.

Comment: But what you actually wrote, `Sum = stuff[i]`, overwrites Sum every iteration without reading it, so the correct optimization is to replace the loop with `Sum = v1[len-1] + v2[len-1]`, i.e. just add the two elements that set the final value of Sum, and don't touch any other elements.

Comment: For cases where `len` isn't a multiple of the vector length, you'd want a cleanup loop at the end, like [The correct way to sum two arrays with SSE2 SIMD in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39759936)

Comment: After the edit, that's an even easier problem to vectorize; it's purely vertical, no reduction, so it can be vectorized for FP data without having to pretend FP math is associative (`-ffast-math`).

Answer (score 1):

Note: This answer assumes `sum =`  is a typo and the OP meant `sum +=`

---

The most important optimizations here are loop unrolling and vectorization.

The pseudocode would look like this:

Some notations and assumptions:

- `v[i : i + 4]` represents a SIMD element, `sum_4` again a SIMD element.
- 16 bytes alignment requirement

```
i = 0
sum_4 = 0..0;

// header
while vec1 + i !aligned at 16 bytes:
    sum_4[0] += vec1[i] + vec2[i];
    ++i

// simd - can be further unrolled with multiple vector registers
while i + 4 < len(vec1)
    sum_4 = vec1[i : i + 4] + vec2[i : i + 4]
    i += 4

// footer
while i < len(vec1)
    sum_4[0] = vec1[i] + vec2[i]
    ++i

// aggregate
int sum = horizontal_add(sum_4)
```

Comment: Note that the code in the question doesn't actually sum the array, it sums the last 2 elements.  But presumably it was intended to be `Sum +=` like your answer is implementing, instead of `Sum =`.  But the OP's self-answer uses `Sum[i] = v[i] + v[i]`, so it's a purely "vertical" vector operation, not a reduction, so no need to unroll with multiple vector accumulators to hide FP latency.

Comment: @PeterCordes I didn't even noticed that. Yes, `sum =` makes no sense as it discards the whole loop and it is most likely a typo.

Answer (score 0):

So, I found this beautiful of a paper by Frances Allen:

[paper](https://www.clear.rice.edu/comp512/Lectures/Papers/1971-allen-catalog.pdf)

Based on her explanation I think I can unroll the vector sum loop by two or four, etc.

here's an example of unrolling the loop by two.

```
for i in range(0, len(v), 2):
    vector_result[i] = v[i] + v[i]
    vector_result[i+1] = v[i+1] + v[i+1]
```

Comment: Yes, and roll that back up into a SIMD operation that does two or four elements at once.  Unrolling to create independent work is the first step of SIMD vectorization.

Comment: @PeterCordes how do I make so it actually optimizes? I tested some python code and the unroll by 2 runs slower than the normal for loop. Any tips?

Comment: In what, CPython?  It's not a compiler, it's a pretty basic interpreter with no ability to optimize.  Write it in a compiled language like C++ or Rust and compile with clang or gcc `-O3 -march=native`.  And don't unroll by hand in the source, that usually just makes it *harder* for compilers to auto-vectorize.  See [C loop optimization help for final assignment (with compiler optimization disabled)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32000917) for some examples of how much it helps to enable optimization in C.  (CPython has no optimizer, but Cython can compile Python to C.)

Comment: I assumed you were just using Python as pseudo-code for the loop logic, in a question about optimizing compilers for various languages.

Comment: Found a better example: [Does compiler use SSE instructions for a regular C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50786580) shows a simple C loop and the resulting compiler output.

Comment: @PeterCordes yea I was using python as pseudo code for optimizing compilers in general. But I wanted to see what happened if I ran the code. So If I take that unrolled loop and compile to assembly it will be faster than a normal loop? I’m building a linear algebra compiler and I want to optimize

Comment: @PeterCordes I am actually building a linear algebra compiler that compiles a simple linear algebra language to Common Lisp and to x86. the loop unrolling will be part of my intermediate language/representation. how do I ensure that this loop unrolling actually optimizes? any tips will be greatly appreciated-- thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249167/discussion-between-sphereinamanifold-and-peter-cordes).